# Unable to compile anything with Lualatex anymore

Tags: luatex

This is a really tough question to draft as I am not really sure what is going on.

I am using TeXStudio and MikTeX on Ubuntu 20.04, and I am supposed to compile a document *only using LuaLaTeX*.

For a while, this worked fine but I ended up installing a couple of packages today on MikTeX and suddenly the document wouldn't compile anymore.

Now, I have reinstalled MikTeX, made sure to re-link MikTeX-LuaLaTeX on TeXStudio compiler, and I can't even get this minimal working example to run.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}

\begin{document}
    hi  
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

```
line 1: Extra \endcsname.
line 1: Missing { inserted.
line 1: Missing control sequence inserted.
line 1: Extra \endcsname.
line 1: Missing { inserted.
line 1: Missing { inserted.
line 1: Extra \endcsname.
line 1: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
line 1: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

Here's the log file for the same, the compiler seems to be looping through the file but doesn't execute anything:
https://pastebin.com/7cZfHm7a

Would really appreciate any leads on this matter, thank you!

EDIT: Removed `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` from the MWE as per comments from @Mico and @David Carlisle.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I can't test now but I think your system is not uptodate. Check for updates in the MiKTeX console in user and admin mode (if there something like user and admin mode on you system)

Comment: you should also show the actual tex log not that summary which is presmably made by your editor. never use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with luatex (it simply will raise an error saying not to use `inputenc`, and you can not easily use latin1 encoded files with luatex, they need to be UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle! I have updated the question according to your comments. The actual tex log is in the link https://pastebin.com/7cZfHm7a, it seemed to large to paste here along with the question.

Given this tex log, do you know what could be happening? MiKTeX is up to date. This error is quite new, I have been able to use lualatex to compile my documents previously without knowing too many details about it.

Comment: Your expl3 version looks to old. You have L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>, I have L3 programming layer <2022-02-05>. Check for update or deinstall/reinstall l3kernel and then recreate the lualatex format.

Answer (score 2):

Under absolutely no circumstance should you be running `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` if your intention is to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile the document.

I was actually utterly unable to reproduce the error messages you report getting. Instead, I got the following:

```
! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.
(inputenc)                only UTF-8 supported.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
```

The upshot? Do *not* load the `inputenc` package if you intend to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile the document.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Mico! I didn't know that I must not use the inputenc package with LuaLaTeX. I just built an MWE using "quick start" on TeXStudio for the purposes of writing this question.

I will make the necessary edits to my question to avoid confusing a future reader.

Nevertheles, despite the change, I am arrive at the same error. All documents compile alright with pdfatex but lualatex is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an answer for my future reference, or for anybody who goes through the same issue.

Thanks a lot to @Mico, @DavidCarlisle and @UlrikeFischer for your responses! Your inputs about my installation being old made sense, so here's what worked in fixing my issue:

1. Uninstall MikTeX
2. Delete broken links in `/bin`
3. Reinstalled MikTeX

It is possible that I was running an old version of MikTeX, and with some older libraries---there was some incompatibility due to this.